# How can I draw a NSImage to fit my NSView?

Tags: objective-c, nsview

I'm working on an todays widget extension that simply shows pictures. Clicking on the picture will load the next and so on.
Some images are wide and soma are slim. I want them to be resized keeping the aspect ratio to fill the width of the notification center which is 320. 
The image itself is contained within an NSImageView and the NSImageView is drawn inside the NSView of the Todays widget.
I always want the view to be as compact as possible but the image should still use it's full width. 
I've been working on this a week now and I can't seem to get it working properly.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Init!");
        _imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
        _model = [[ImageViewModel alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"View did load!");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _image = [_model getImage];
    [_imageView setImage:_image];
    [self alignView];
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}

- (void)alignView {
    float oldWidth = _image.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = 320 / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = _image.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;


    NSRect newRect = NSMakeRect(0, 320-newHeight, newWidth, newHeight);
    [_imageView setFrame:newRect];
    self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.preferredContentSize.width, 

    newHeight);
}
```

This is the code that resizes the image. Some pictures get scaled properly and some are cut off downwards in the middle. I just want the pictures to use the full width of the notification center but still keeping the correct aspect ratio. The notification center should then respond to the scaled image size by cropping the space vertically this particular widget uses so no space is wasted. 
My code totally behaves strange. It seems the images are drawn from the top and sometimes they are cut in the middle but without the next widget aligning to the lower border of the image. There is much space left. 
It seems the view of the widget has the correct height but the image is just not drawn fully. 
Some pictures are even not fully using the width and many don't start at the TopLeft point. I guess my code is very bad.

I would really need some help on this.

```
Notification Center |  Actual Image | What it should be | If Image is smaller
    ----------         ----------        ----------        ----------
    Widget1            Widget1           Widget1           Widget1
    ----------         ----------        ----------        ----------
    Widget2            Widget2           Widget2           Widget2

    ----------         ----------        ----------        ----------
    ImageWidget        ----------        Image.....        Image.....
                       Image.....        ..........        ..........
                       ..........        ..........        ..........
                       ----------        ..........        ----------
                       Free space        ..........        next Widget
                       Free space        ..........
   ----------          ----------        ----------
   next Widget         next Widget       next Widget
```

I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: Have you tried [`NSImage drawInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/drawInRect:) so that it draws within the bounds you specify?

Comment: If I use 'drawInRect the' image gets drawn half way in the widget, not at the top.